# Can't pack singularity sanbox into sif container

Tags: build, conda, singularity-container

I'm using singularity to build a container containing a conda environment ([QIIME](https://qiime2.org/)). I have already set the conda environment inside the singularity sandbox. And I want to build an auto-active conda environment container by [a definition script](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/definition_files.html). This is my def file, `singularity_qiime`:

```
Bootstrap: localimage
From: /path/to/container/qiime2_v2021.11_sandbox


%post
  echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT
  echo "conda activate qiime2_v2021.11" >> $SINGULARITY_ENVIRONMENT
```

And this is my command:

```
sudo singularity build qiime2_v2021.11_sanda.sif  singularity_qiime
```

After waiting a while (actually quite long), I got the error:

```
INFO:    Starting build...
INFO:    Running post scriptlet
source: /opt/conda/envs/qiime2_v2021.11/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-binutils_linux-64.sh:10:40: parameter expansion requires a literal
source: /opt/conda/envs/qiime2_v2021.11/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-gcc_linux-64.sh:10:40: parameter expansion requires a literal
source: /opt/conda/envs/qiime2_v2021.11/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-gfortran_linux-64.sh:10:40: parameter expansion requires a literal
source: /opt/conda/envs/qiime2_v2021.11/etc/conda/activate.d/activate-gxx_linux-64.sh:10:40: parameter expansion requires a literal
FATAL:   command "R CMD javareconf" was killed after 5s timeout
FATAL:   While performing build: while running engine: exit status 255
```

I have searched for the error `FATAL: command "R CMD javareconf" was killed after 5s timeout` on Google but it is no clue. Could someone who has experience tell me what the problem is? Thanks.